# handlebars.js Trying to pass an json array into a helper function and then itrerate it

Tags: json, handlebars.js

I am new to Handlebars.js and I have a json object, which includes a child array of more objects.
I have figured out how to access the data in the web page using the following syntax {{{V.0.D}}} V being the name of the child array, 0 being this iteration, and D being a particular property of the child array.

I am having trouble however passing the V array to a helper and figuring out how to iterate over this array so that I can return data from one of the child objects.

Here is my helper so far:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getRegion', function (descData) {
    for (desc in descData) {
        console.log('descData.D:' + desc.D);
    }

    return something;

});
```

Here is my caller:

```
{{getRegion V}}
```

I keep getting a desc.D is undefined error.

I don't think I need a block helper because I am not needing to list all of the child objects.

I am sure this is simple, but I just cannot figure out what I am missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for in` should be used to loop on enumerable properties of an object. Here is a reference from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Your helper should be modified as

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getRegion', function (descData) {
    for (index in descData) {
        console.log('descData.D:' + descData[index].D);
    }

    return something;

});
```

Here is the helper using an array's `forEach`

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getRegion', function (descData) {
    var str = '';
    descData.forEach(function(desc) {
        console.log('descData.D:' + desc.D);
        str += ' '+ desc.D;
    });

    return str ;

});
```